# calculate textarea data using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a text area ,and i have some default value in it

```
 <textarea rows="10" cols="50" id="textarea">   
John: 2

Jane: 3

John: 4

Jane: 5 
</textarea>
```

I want to find the total of John or Jane when a button is clicked.also to do the same calculation when a new value is entered by any user .

*needs in JavaScript

I appreciate any suggestions or sample code

Comment: How are you enforcing that the user enters data in the correct format, which will be fairly essential for this.

Comment: you can use lodash to calculate it, will be easy.

Comment: @DavidThomas ,am focusing on the calculation for now first,i know the validation is important for maintaining the split operation

Comment: @Esti for now i can create an object from a static string but the problem is i have to get the values from the textarea ,convert it into an array and then try converting it into an object, at-least that's the direction i am trying.please provide any suggestions to this approach!

Comment: This is one of my plnkr ,that am working thiis on (incomplete) http://plnkr.co/edit/owhumZZE3IIBuYrDwuVh?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very strange way to enter this kind of data!

Anyway you may try something like this (also strange:-):

```
var result = {};
document.getElementById('textarea').value.match(/\w+:\s+\d+/g)
.forEach(function(element) {
    var data = element.match(/(\w+):\s+(\d+)/),
        name = data[1],
        value = data[2];
    if (typeof result[name] == 'undefined') {
        result[name] = 0;
    }
    result[name] += +value;
});
console.log(result);
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0mmw9wcm/1/)

Comment: "When it doesn't work, you should always try to know why" (antique Chinese proverb). Now it works...

Answer (score 1):

A simple and quick way is:

```
var lines = $("#textarea").text().split("\n");
var names = new Array();
var sum = new Array();
for(var i=0;i<lines.length-1;i++){
    var line = lines[i].split(": ");
    var index = names.indexOf(line[0]);
    if(index>-1){
        sum[index] += Number(line[1]);
    }else{
        names.push(line[0]);
        sum.push(Number(line[1]));
    }
}
console.log(names);
console.log(sum);
```

Working:

[image: Working of the above code]

Comment: Hello @Anand, thank you for the sample the sum is returning Nan,and do you have any suggestions on if we can have the results in a key value format!

Comment: Hmm, that's a bit weird. Anyways, you can find the working example here - http://jsbin.com/cutitisiso/1/edit?html,console,output